# Getting product category ids in Magento block

Tags: php, magento

Is there some kind of black magic involved in retrieving the list of categories associated with a product inside a Block in Magento?

I've tried this:

```
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() AS $item) {
    $categories = $item->getCategoryIds();
    Mage::log(get_class($item));
    Mage::log(print_r($categories, true));

    $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
    Mage::log(get_class($prod));
    Mage::log(print_r($prod->getCategoryIds(), true));
```

And what I get is:

```
2014-11-21T08:59:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
2014-11-21T08:59:25+00:00 DEBUG (7):
2014-11-21T08:59:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
2014-11-21T08:59:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)
```

I also tried using the `$prod` object's `getCategoryCollection()` method but I can't seem to get any data out of that `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection` object either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$item->getId() doesn't give you product id, it gives you quote item id. You may use $item->getProductId().

Try this instead;

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
Mage::log(print_r($prod->getCategoryIds(), true));
```

Comment: And you will get a blank array in your system.log only if there is no category assigned to a Product. (Line no. 4 in your code)
There is no black magic. Use a standard IDE like netbeans, and refer the classes and their functions. They are sufficient to find an answer.

Comment: You are wrong. In line 4 of his code, he tries to get category ids from a quote item object. You can't get category ids from a quote item object.

Comment: Pardon, but please double check his code before your comment. 
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
It returns him an object of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.
So he can get categories associated with it by using $prod->getCategoryIds(), But since there are no categories assigned to the product, it reurns an empty array.
Mage::log(print_r($prod->getCategoryIds(), true));

Comment: That is line 6. And it may return object, but doesn't load a product. Becuase $item->getId() doesn't give a "product id". Double check yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was talking about line 4 of the log file.

Comment: Duh, for some reason I assumed the id of the quote item was the same as the product id. ``$item->getProductId()`` solved it. Thanks!

Comment: @Harit I didn't want to speak harshly but you accused me twice, I feel sorry now, I hope you to have a nice weekend. You are a good guy also, trying to help people.

Comment: No worries. Actually it was my mistake, firstly, I wrote a misleading comment unintentionally , and later on, I didn't read the code entirely before commenting. Apologies. It's people like you who correct my mistakes. To err is human to self correct is to learn. Best wishes to you as well sir.